# What is query returning in the same time for 2 rows vs 2000 rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that when has a variable that is an `IN` clause:  `IN ('123', '456')`

- If I put two items in the `IN()` clause, the query returns in 4 seconds
- If I put 200 items in the `IN()` clause, the query still returns in 4 seconds

The query is a nested query.

I have tried tuning, indexing, and adding OPTIONS(FAST x) to the query. Turned `ARITHABORT ON` and a few others, with no difference.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET ARITHABORT ON;
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;

SELECT columns
FROM
    (SELECT columns 
     FROM
         (SELECT columns 
          FROM 
              (SELECT columns 
               FROM sometable 
               CROSS JOIN xyz_table) Level1
         ) Level2
    ) Level3
WHERE
    items IN ('123', '456'));
```

I would expect the results to come back faster with a smaller amount of items to filter.

Comment: Deeply nested queries like this can be real performance killers.  You might want to show us the actual SQL or problem, in case we can come up with a better approach.

Comment: where in is not performant, I recommand to put your items to check in a temporary table and make an inner join

Comment: @KemalALGAZZAH perhaps an inner join would be more appropriate?

Comment: @SeanLange, absolutely ! for some reason, I was thinking the condition was "not in", and it is "in" in such case inner join is preferable

Comment: If you don't have indexes both queries can be doing a full table scan, in this case, the only diff in time will be the output IO (negligible in most cases)

Answer (score 1):

4 seconds is **LONG TIME** for Sql Server, whether you're using 2 items or 200. I also see this:

> The query is a nested query

I suggest something other than this  `IN()` clause is driving the performance here.

But 200 items in an `IN()` clause is neither typical nor especially good practice. You're generally much better off finding a way to write a `SELECT` statement defining those items, and then writing `JOIN` or `APPLY` against that `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I suggest is a follows: replace the condition `where in` by an `inner join` (a nested query) to a temporay table in which you store the values to look for.

The script would be some thing like this

1. First insert the items you are looking for, in `myTempTable`
2. then run a script like this one

   ```
   select t1.* 
   from myTable t1 
   inner join myTemTable t2 on t1.items = t2.items
   ```